# Popup in HTML/JS pops up only with two clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a very simple HTML/JS code to "pop" dictionary entries, just a very basic "Wikipedia's references" lookalike. With some problems, otherwise I wouldn't bother SO :) BTW, I am not very skilled in HTML/CSS/JS, it might be something really stupid I'm doing!

The first and foremost problem: the popups works, but after *clicking twice*. I really don't know why. The first click does nothing, the second correctly makes my popup box appear.

The second problem is optional, really. Here it is: the boxes appear on the left of the screen. Is it possible to place them *under the link* I'm clicking? Of course, independently of the link position.

Note: I am now using `span`s, but using a link does nothing different.

Thanks & Cheers!

HTML:

```
<p class="text">
The text will contain dictionary entries, as an example, the
<span class="dict" onclick="showHide('thekey')">following entry</span>.
<span class="entry" id="thekey">
Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet. 
</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.dict {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    background-color: #f69292;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.entry {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: white;
    min-height: 128px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ff8080;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
// Show or hide a dictionary
function showHide(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
    else
        e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: "the boxes appear on the left of the screen..." what boxes?

Comment: The `span` that contains the Lorem text, they are rendered as "boxes".

Answer (score 2):

The reason its not working on a single click is because of the following code:

```
if (e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
else
    e.style.display = 'none';
```

What this does is check the value of the inline styling to the element. Since, you have made use of a class, it doesn't quite give you the value, instead ending up with a blank. So you can change it to this:

```
if (e.style.display == 'none' || e.style.display == '') {
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can see this here->http://jsfiddle.net/W9fqb/1/

With respect to your second part of the question, if you want to place them in the next line
then `position:relative` can help you out. However, since you are looking to place them under the link (like a tooltip) then you can make use of third-party tools that will save much time & effort (example [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos)).

**UPDATE :**

Just to show how Tooltipster can be used to achieve your desired output: http://jsfiddle.net/W9fqb/2/

**Note:** This works on `hover` at the moment, but if you see their docs, you will be able to acheive this on mouse-click, that is the way you want.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yep! It was this! Do you happen to know how I can place that box under the `span`? That would be totally awesome!

Comment: @senseiwa You can check out the **Tooltipster** link I have provided. A combination of *Custom show / hide triggers* and *Multiple tooltips on a single element* (part of the demos) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: That is very interesting! But as I am learning how to do this, I was trying to avoid jQuery & Co. (BTW, the look is really cool, I'll use that!)

Comment: @senseiwa I've updated my answer with a fiddle. Take a look at it to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the two-clicks part, changing order works with javascript:

```
// Show or hide a dictionary
function showHide(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: For info: element.style only refers to the inline style. Directly attached to the HTML element. So in the first run the return value of `e.style.display is ""`. There is another method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle to get the "current style"